# ListBox , DataTemplate and Triggers

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

i got a DataTemplate for a listboxitem and i want to create a triger , so when a user click an item the background will change and also the label

my code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="RoundedItem" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="listViewItem_MouseDoubleClick" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border Name="ItemBorder" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="1" Background="Transparent">
                        <Label Name="ItemLabel" Foreground="Red" >
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Label>
                    </Border>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="ItemBorder" Property="Background" Value="DeepSkyBlue" />
                            <Setter TargetName="ItemLabel" Property="Foreground" Value="Orange" />
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>

            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="TitleTemplate" DataType="models:Title" >
        <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding ThumbFilePath}" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="5,5,5,5"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
```

What happend is that the TextBlock change his color and not the label..

anyone know why ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TextBlock` inherits the Foreground definition from its parents in the visual tree. The `Label`, on the other hand, defines the Foreground in its default style.

Your approach is "non-WPF-like" - you shouldn't wrap the `ContentPresenter` in a `Label` control.

The right approach depends on whether you want **all** text in the item to change its Foreground, or just the label?

*[In both cases, there's no apparent benefit to using a `Label` in the data template - so I'll assume that the label is changed to `TextBlock`.]*

If the answer to the above question is that all text should be changed: in the `ControlTemplate` of the `ListBoxItem`, in the trigger for IsSelected, from the seccond setter remove `TargetName="ItemLabel"` so the final setter is:

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange" />
```

This will change the foreground of the item that will affect the foreground of both `TextBlock`s in the data template.

If you want to affect just one of the TextBlocks:

```
1. remove the setter for the foreground from the control template
2. add a trigger to your data template:

<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
        <Image .../>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Text01" ..../>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Text02" ..../>
    </StackPanel>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Text01" Property="Foreground" Value="Orange"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Side note: if you **have** to use `Label` control in your data template, bind its Foreground property to the Foreground of the list box item, like so:

```
<Label Foreground="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"....../>
```

If this doesn't help, it means that your list box item inherits its foreground, so use:

```
<Label Foreground="{Binding TextElement.Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"....../>
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to tack on to this that I was experiencing a similar problem where I'd added a ListBox.ItemTemplate to my ListBox, and the styling then did not apply to the text anymore.

What I was doing was trying to display a list of languages (CultureInfo) for the user to select from, however I wanted the native names to display, not the English name. For some reason, not all languages have their native names capitalized in their CultureInfo, and NativeName is the only instance of their name, so I needed to apply a function to the CultureInfo.NativeName to capitalize the names myself. To accomplish this, I added the ItemTemplate with a Data Template inside, on which I applied a converter.

```
<ListBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinHeight="200" x:Name="cbLanguages" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SupportedCultures, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource CultureResourcesDS}}"
    FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="300" Margin="10"
    Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxTemplate}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource NativeNameConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

After a while of searching, I came across XAMeLi's answer here, and **changed the Label I'd put in the DataTemplate to a TextBox, and the ListBoxItemStyle I'd created worked again.**

Basically, Labels and TextBoxes have different traits that can be exploited, or can cause annoying issues in this case. Here's a good explanation with some examples of the differences: http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/differences-between-label-and-textblock/